# Rails Complex Form is Failing to Save Due to Parent ID Being Blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm using rails 4.2.4, Ruby 2.2.1p85 and MySQL 5.5.

I'm having an issue getting a rails complex form to save due to the parent object's id being blank.  Of course its blank it has not been created yet.  I have a list of countries already in the database and am attempting to add one to a newly created facility.  Each facility belongs to a country.  The facility is the parent form and the fields_for contains the following:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :country do |country| %>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= country.label :Country, 'Facility Country:' %>
  <%= country.select :id, options_from_collection_for_select(@countries, 
      "id", "name"), {include_blank: "Select a Country..."}, {class: "form-control"} %>
</div>
```

Here is the error:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BbcFacilitiesController#create
Couldn't find BbcCountry with ID=3 for BbcFacility with ID=

# POST /facilities.json
  def create
    @facility = Facility.new(facility_params)

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @facility.save
```

It's getting the correct country id in the params object, but since the facility has not yet been created it doesn't know what to do.  It just attempts to save it with a blank id in facility.  How can I resolve this issue?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually setting the country id before the `@facility.save`, to stop activerecord looking for the country joined with facility. To be properly sure try stripping out the "country_attributes" key from the params.

It should be something like:

```
country_attr = facility_params.delete "country_attributes"
@facility = Facility.new(facility_params)
@facility.country_id = country_attr["id"]
```

Edit: added note about stripping out country attributes.

Comment: That causes the same problem.  The issue is occurring on this line:
@facility = Facility.new(facility_params)

Comment: Oh, BTW, the country_id already exists in the params object, its facility that's missing.  Setting the country id would not have any affect.

Comment: Hmn, could you paste the contents of the relevant POST request from the server logs? So we can see an example of what params you have.

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LDGFFOIJEOIJRMLOCVIUOSRWE==", "facility"=>{"name"=>"Joe Blow", "url"=>"http://www.google.com", "country_attributes"=>{"id"=>"2"}, "addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"street"=>"123 F Street", "city"=>"browning", "state"=>"NV"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Facility", "controller"=>"facilities", "action"=>"create"}